# why does itunes "optimize" my photos every time i sync

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization, windows, photos

Every time I sync my ipod touch, I sit there and watch "optimizing photos x of 1000" which takes forever.

To be clear, I am not adding any more photos.  Shouldn't this only be a one time thing to optimize photos?
Why does it need to do this step every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure why it does it every time, but the 'optimising' is basically shrinking their dimensions to the iPod screen size, thus saving space on the iPod.

I would therefore assume that it does it every time as it doesn't save the 'optimised' ones in order to save space on the computer.

Comment: @Samuel Walker - that seems a bit insane.  don't you think??

Comment: Perhaps, but that is how I understand the iTunes / iPod Photo handling procedure. Thinking the answer is insane is not a reason for down voting when that answer is correct.

Comment: You're right about why, but it shouldn't be doing it every time. OP, are you clearing caches, or moving/deleting iTunes' folders?

Comment: I would think that it would only optimize new photos.  IE photos that have not yet been optimized and uploaded onto the device.  Sounds like a db problem on the iPod.  Try formatting and restoring.

Comment: @Nathan G. - i am not clearing caches, etc . .

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a windows computer or a Mac OS computer?
Check properties in itunes for options related to photos.
If you're on Mac OS check the iPhoto program for similar "ipod" options.

Comment: windows